# Jinja2.10 included file only indent the first row?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

Im trying to update from jinja2.8 to 2.10, and have a problem.
In 2.8, my code like:

```
Case:
{% filter indent(2) %}
{% include "work.tpl" without context %}
{% endfilter %}
End
```

work.tpl like this:

```
Row 1
Row 2
```

So, result was:

```
Case:
  Row 1
  Row 2
End
```

But when i upgraded to 2.10, my result is:

```
Case:
  Row 1
Row2
End
```

How can I do like jinja2.8 in 2.10. Please help me!

My file here:
main.py

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template('template.tpl')
rendered = template.render()
print(str(rendered))
```

template.tpl here:

```
Test
    {% filter indent(4, first=True) -%}
    {% include 'template2.tpl' without context %}
    {%- endfilter %}
Test
```

And the template2.tpl here:

```
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
```

And the result is

```
Test
    Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Test
```

Answer (score 0):

From a short test I can't reproduce this. Here's the simplified code I used:

```
import jinja2

tmpl = jinja2.Template("""
Case:
{% filter indent(2, first=True) -%}
Row 1
Row 2
{%- endfilter %}
End
""")

print(tmpl.render())
```

Which prints:

```
Case:
  Row 1
  Row 2
End
```

I only added the `first=True` option and the dashes on the inner tags to `filter`, but that shouldn't make the difference, so I assume there's something else going on in your `work.tpl`.

Comment: I have edited my post. When I try your code it work perfect but I don't know why my code still not work :(